# how to align the number in MarkerClusterer icon?

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have using google map api v3 and i want to display custom cluster pin with number alignment like this:

[image]

I have tried this code:

```
var clusterOptions = {
        zoomOnClick: false,
        styles: [{height: 36, width: 36, url: location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1)+'images/pushpin_cluster.png' }]}
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);
```

But it's showing like this:

[image]

how can i align the Cluster icon number into the blue box.

thanks in advance...

Comment: what css you applying on that blue box ? and that no. is inside that box or not.

Comment: blue box is image not css. the no.is not in blue box.

Comment: ok. Is blue box merged with that ring ? and if yes then share the css for that. Actually share the css for parent of that no.

Comment: question is updated. i did not used any extra css.

Comment: Try with `achor` values (*The anchor position of the label text*). Check for example [advanced_example.html](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html). You will see there different `anchor` values for different icon sizes. For example `anchor: [24, 0],`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tried this code is working well:

```
var clusterOptions = {
        zoomOnClick: false,        
        styles: [{ anchor:[2,22],textColor: "white",height: 36, width: 36, url: location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1)+'images/pushpin_cluster.png' }]}
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);
```

**anchor:[2,22]** -The position (in pixels) from the center of the cluster icon to where the text label is to be centered and drawn. The format is [yoffset, xoffset] where yoffset increases as you go down from center and xoffset increases to the right of center. The default is [0, 0].

Comment: For v3 google maps API `anchor` changed to `anchorText`. Spent few hours to figure this one out. Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1124

Comment: gotta be said that any box-sizing other than content-box messes up with this

Answer (score 2):

If u are using [markerclustererplus library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.2/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html#), then u can override that library code.

```
/**
 * Adding the cluster icon to the dom.
 * @ignore
 */

ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  this.div_ = document.createElement('DIV');
  if (this.visible_) {
    var pos = this.getPosFromLatLng_(this.center_);
    this.div_.style.cssText = this.createCss(pos);

    var innerHtml;

    if (this.cluster_.markers_.length > 0) {
        innerHtml = "<div><p id='clusterIconText'>" + this.sums_.text + "</p></div>";
    }

    this.div_.innerHTML = innerHtml;
  }

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.div_);

  var that = this;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function() {
    that.triggerClusterClick();
  });
};
```

By css you can change style according to requirement like this

```
 #clusterIconText
        {
            margin-top:-70px;
            margin-left:-70px; 
            color:#f2f2f2;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer because while chimbu's answer started me off, it didn't completely *explain the issue. Each object in the styles array is associates with one of the five cluster icons you can provide, and it seems that providing styles objects will override your imagePath property (since, in my case, providing only one styles object with no url, expecting the imagePath to still work, broke everything). Here's the code I use now:

```
new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    maxZoom: 16,
    ignoreHidden: true,
    styles: [
      ..._.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], () => ({
        textColor: 'black',
        url: './img/cluster/m1.png',
        height: 52,
        width: 53,
        anchorText: [2, 2]
      }))
    ]
  });
```

If you had 5 different images, you could tap into the first argument to the callback and adjust the numbers (1, 2, etc...) to do some math to make the height, width, and anchortext larger/smaller. You can also, of course, only provide one object to the styles array that will be applied to every cluster icon if you wish, but this example provides a bit of flexible and customization if you need it.